# jquery dialog loads content only for first time

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, dialog

I have got the following dialog in jquery that displays the panel contents but it only loads the content for the first time. On the second click it only displays modal overlay. How do I load content on each click?

```
asp:Panel ID="pnlCertificate" runat="server">
   <img id="imgCertificate" runat="server" style="position: relative;" /> 
</asp:Panel>

<div style="display: none">
   <div id="openDialog" style="text-align: center; position: relative; width: 956px; overflow-x: auto;">
   </div>
</div>


function viewCertificate() {
        $("#openDialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            width: 1000,
            height: 700,
            autoOpen: true,
            open: function () {
                $('#openDialog').append($("[id$=pnlCertificate]").html());
                $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').addClass('dialogButton');
                $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').addClass('dialogTitle');
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $("#openDialog").remove();
            },
            buttons: [
            {
                text: "Print",
                "class": 'printButton',
                click: function () {

                }
            },
            {
                text: "Close",
                "class": 'closeButton',
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
          ]
        });
        $("[id$=btnPreview]").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#openDialog").dialog("open");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't .remove() destroying your container? Try .empty() instead?